# How to save a list of objects in a file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

I am trying to save a list of objects (containing files URI) to a file in ASP.NET MVC so that when I load the page, the saved files URI will be loaded and displayed. When I tried it in Windows Forms, it works perfectly, however, I cannot get it working in MVC.

As a reference, the following is the code which I am using in Windows Forms to save the list of objects in a file and to load the contents of the file.

```
private void Save(List<Uri> list)
{
   BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
   FileStream file = File.Create(fileName);
   b.Serialize(file, list.ToList());
   file.Close();
}

private void LoadFile()
{
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        fileList = (List<Uri>)b.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Loading File!");
    }
}
```

When I put the same code in the Controller class, I am getting an error in the following lines:

```
FileStream file = File.Create(fileName);

FileStream file = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
```

**Error:**

**'Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context**

My controller name is "FilesController" but I don't think that it is conflicting the names.

Any help would be very appreciated! :) 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Define "didn't work".  How does it fail?  Writing to a file from .NET code is the same regardless of what type of application is doing it.  It's worth noting in this case that you're catching all exceptions, ignoring those exceptions, and displaying a generic error message.  However, in a web application, `MessageBox.Show()` clearly won't do anything.

Comment: I have just edited my post and specified in which lines I am getting the errors! Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: `I am getting an error in the following lines` <= As already pointed out you need to include the error in your question. Include the Exception Type, the Message, the Stack Trace, and repeat this for any inner exceptions.

Comment: Has it occurred to you to *read the error message*?

Comment: I have edited my post again - Included the errors
Sorry for the hassle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 'Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

The `Controller` class [has a member called `File` already](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx).  (A method, as the error states.)  So when you do this in your controller:

```
File.Create(fileName);
```

The first reference to something called `File` is that method, which makes this line invalid.  If you want to use the `System.IO.File` object, you have to specify that:

```
System.IO.File.Create(fileName);
```

Ideally such dependency-based operations wouldn't happen in a controller.  But for simplicity it's not entirely uncommon to do these in a controller if the app doesn't do much in the first place.

Comment: It worked! However, the following are additional comments:

If you don't specify the file path where you want to save the file, MVC project will save it by default in the IIS Express folder and apparently access is denied to read/write to this folder.

Therefore, instead of specifying the file name in 
     System.IO.File.Create()
it is better to specify the file path where you want to save it.

Comment: @user2950895: Well, yes, ideally one would always specify where one wants to save a file.  Never leave it up to the application to guess.  A common approach is to identify a file name or base root path in the application's configuration and for all file operations to use that.